# Does convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ imply convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sqrt{a_{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that we can guarantee convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sqrt{a_{n}}$ if $a_{n}$ is a decreasing sequence by the Leibnitz test. But what if nothing is mentioned about $a_{n}$?
Can anyone provide me with a counter example if this is wrong?
(Assume all $a_{n}$ are positive)

Comment: $a_n=\frac 1{n^{2}}$ if $n$ is even and $0$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Your question title says you know for sure that the sum $a_n$ is a convergent series; that is already a lot mentioned about $a_n$

Comment: Beautiful example. Thanks a lot!!!!!. Please make this an answer and I'll upvote and mark it as answer .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The OP wants all $a_n > 0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: So $\frac1{n^4}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: OP didn't mean strictly positive as seen from the comment above. But If you want $a_n >0$ you can take $a_n=\frac  1{n^{4}}$ for $n$ odd. @PaulFrost

Comment: @PaulFrost . I just wanted $a_{n}\geq 0$ so that the square root is defined. but as you pointed out , $a_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{4}}$ works out well. Thanks.